# Is there a way to find out which variables changed value in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts

I am working on a userscript and trying to find out which variable I have to change to achieve the same goal as if I was using the UI (the website is not mine). So basically I want to start monitoring all variables, perform the change in UI and, as a result, see which variables changed their values. Is that possible with some browser add-ons or dev tools?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Examine,_modify,_and_watch_variables this might help (it is old), but you can sort of do what you want to do. It might be easier to just look at the code in the normal dev tools and see what does what and then change things accordingly.

Comment: thanks @dobson , but it looks like the regular dev-tool/firebug feature. The problem is, there are thousands variables on the page and it is hard to figure out, which one holds the value that I'm searching for. That's why I am looking for a way to identify the variable which has had its value changed between 2 points in time.